# Appropriate noisy optimization method

Tags: optimization, noise

Say we want to minimize a function $f(x)$ for $x$ in the interval $(0, 1)$.  We can't query $f(x)$, and the gradient is not available; instead we can only sample from $f(x) + \epsilon$ where $\epsilon$ is a random variable representing the noise, and the noise may be a lot larger than the signal.  We only want to store a small constant amount of information between queries.  We can assume $f(x)$ isn't too complicated - it's okay to assume it is convex.  What would be an appropriate method to use here?

Comment: I don't know about the noise but you could try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_evolution.

Comment: Bayesian optimization can be useful in these circumstances. Plenty of questions about bayesian optimization on this site https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bayesian+optimization

Comment: @jcken The problem I see there is that Bayesian optimization tries to approximate all of f.  That could require tracking a lot of information about f at different points, but I only want to use constant space (and constant time per function evaluation).

Comment: @user2974951 Differential evolution looks like it has the same problem that simulated annealing has with noise: the noise makes the algorithm too willing to abandon a good solution for a bad one that "got lucky" on noise. I implemented a quick test of DE in one dimension and I do see this problem. Without noise it settles very closely to the minimum, but with noise, the solutions do not settle and are distributed randomly near the minimum.

Comment: DE has a few parameters more than SA, you may have to play around with them to try and improve the search (to mitigate the noise). I would try decreasing the scaling factor (aka learning rate) and the recombination probability (lower variation).

Comment: @user2974951 the recombination probability actually doesn't matter in 1 dimension using the algorithm here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_evolution#Algorithm because it always recombines at least one dimension, and there's only one. Changing the scaling factor or population size doesn't make a difference. The problem is there's nothing to average out the noise. If instead of taking one sample, on step n we summed n samples and divided by n, that would work because it would average out the noise, but of course it would be very sample-inefficient.

Comment: @user2974951 I think a winning method should do some kind of exponentially-discounted averaging of values.

Comment: You are looking for [stochastic optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Stochastic_optimization). For example, there's [Bayesian optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_optimization) as mentioned, and I would also suggest looking into [Simultaneous Perturbation Stochastic Approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_perturbation_stochastic_approximation). My guess is that you would find good success by fitting a quadratic regression, and then take the next estimate as its extreme point.